# retrieve parameter from http header to java

Tags: java, http, header

I have this webservice and to test it i used SOAPui,
when i start the rest request i get a response with:

```
    GET http://localhost:8080/sApi/v1/myapp? 
    ic01=1&fields=site.id%2Csite.name HTTP/1.1
    Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
    Application-Name: TEST
```

The last parameter Application-Name i have added it manually [in SOUPui] and i have to retriever it from eclipse ! 
i wanted to try !

```
    String Application-Name=response.getHeaders("Application-Name");
```

but it's wrong ! 
can you help me please any ideas ?

Comment: What is wrong about it? Also, I don't believe you are allowed to use the '-' character in a variable name and may want to rename it to "application_name."

Comment: @Matthew Yes you are totally right, so i added the attribute (parameter) on SOAPui and i want to retrieve it in java so when i do the request, in the response i want to have the attribute that i added ! am i clear ?

Comment: What I mean is, did eclipse give you an error code? Is the string just blank? Can you post the error code?

Comment: i have fixed it @Matthew Thank you for your time. applicationname=request.getHeaders("Application-Name").nextElement();